# pattern matching number of digits

Tags: sql, pattern-matching

I need to parse digits out of a string when the length is 4 or >.
I have a test query. I need the number after '66' I also need it to return a blank if no match is found.

```
DECLARE @Str nvarchar(1000)

SET @Str  =  'ANDERSON, Doe 66 M - MEDICAL  ONCOLOGY 40225   (DFCI)'
--SET @Str  =  'NTW LOANER - TELECOMMUNICATIONS    (DFCI)'


SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, 
          PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',@str)+1, 
          PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',
                   SUBSTRING(@str, 
                             PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',@str)+1, 
                             LEN(@str))
                   + ' ')-1);
```

Comment: What's the database engine? As of 2018, SQL Server hasn't yet implemented regular expression matching.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it: you repeat the pattern x number of times; I settled on 3.

```
SUBSTRING(s.Description, 
      PATINDEX('% [0-9][0-9][0-9]%',s.Description)+1, 
      PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',
               SUBSTRING(s.Description, 
                         PATINDEX('% [0-9][0-9][0-9]%',s.Description)+1, 
                         LEN(s.Description))
               + ' ')-1);
```